# Will my iOS 5 app be visible in the App Store for iOS 4 users?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I'm considering submitting an app that will only support iOS 5. When iOS 4 users peruse the App Store, will they be able to see my app? If so, what happens if they try to install the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, it will in fact be visible to all iOS users. If the user tries to download the app, an error message will pop up stating:

> This application requires iOS 5.0. You must update to iOS 5.0 in order to download and use this application.

Comment: Thanks. I figured as much. It's understandable that Apple would use new apps to entice their users to upgrade.